# The drawbacks of a reward point system

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, up-votes

I have been using SO and I think I have over 100 questions so I am pretty experienced with it. The reward system works pretty well except of a few drawbacks from usages for the sake of gaining points:

1- To fend off bad/half-assed/useless/irrelevant answers, my questions tend to be specific and include [as much information as possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59144/short-questions-vs-long-questions-as-defense-against-i-know-these-answers-alre). If I am looking for something specific, I post very specific requirements. I get answers from people who seem to just Googled the question and did a copy of paste. Their solution is far from satisfying the requirements.
Example: I need a network sniffer that does this and this and this and this. I get a flood of 'WireShark' recommendations just because its a popular product. Do they ACTUALLY know it satisfies my requirements. NO. They mention it just because they HEARD its good.

2- I get an answer. It gets one upvote. I leave a comment indicating it actually doesn't answer the question and I leave a reason. You would think people read the comment. No. The answer gets a lot of subsequent upvotes!! Upvoting for the sake of upvoting and getting points. Then the question doesn't get anymore answers. I guess users think if an answer has many upvotes, it must be the right answer? No it didn't and I mention this. and then the question loses steam and no one bothers offering more help. Frustrating.

([similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22024/problems-with-stack-overflows-reputation-point-system))

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: You bring up some interesting points.  Do you have a proposed solution?  Or is this post just for awareness.

Comment: [Your SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/129001/tony-henrich) shows 225 questions and 25 answers and nearly 1400 rep. I make that about six rep per post.

Comment: Do you have any links for situation #2?

Comment: @dmckee: and what does that mean as a conclusion?

Comment: @jjnguy: yes awareness and ranting. There's no solution to changing person's behavior.

Comment: I don't remember which question. Why do you ask, you don't believe that this is happening?

Comment: @Diago; when the tag says 'discussion', what does that mean to you?

Comment: @Tony: I believe it happens, but I've also seen people ask questions and accept wrong answers.  The person asking the question isn't always the best person to judge the quality of an answer, which is why we also have voting (and not *just* acceptance).  If lots of people are voting up an answer despite your comments, then maybe your comment is just wrong.  Links would help alleviate my doubts.

Comment: @Tony. That there is at least a question to discuss and not a senseless rant? Like any of the other discussion tagged **questions**?

Comment: @Tony You say you're experienced with the system. OK, looks that way. However, you are averaging about 1 net upvote per questions. If that was me, I wonder what I could do to make my questions better. 'Course, I'm always harping on the need for better writing, so make of it what you will.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: People tend to upvote the popular, looks good, looks logical, the motherload answer even though it's NOT the answer to the current question. Take my sniffer example. Lots of people would upvote Wireshark. Hey it's popular and so full of features you would think it can toast bread. But it doesn't meet MY very specific requirements. I accept an answer of an obscure no one heard of sniffer which works for me. To me, Wireshark is the wrong answer. The right should be the answer to the specific question. Not the one that everyone liked.

Comment: @Tony: am I overlooking a link? Why are you not willing to point to an example?

Comment: @dmckee: You know.. I am the last person who cares about earning points. Most of my points are earned due to questions. Whether I earn 1 or 10, it doesn't matter. Sometimes I ask obscure questions where only very few in the world can answer. Does this mean I can get very few points? OK so be it. I am on SO to solve my problems at work. Not to earn points. I would leave this to gaming systems. When I said I have experience, I meant I have asked a lot of questions and I can now anticipate the answers I am getting. Most I will ignore. I will wait for the gold nugget.

Comment: @dmckee: If you look at the questions I posted on meta the past two days, they are about the friction SO  is putting for me to get the gold nugget answer. The quick closing of questions. The rush to say a question is a duplicate. and so on..

Comment: @Tony: Yes, I agree with all that, but maybe Wireshark does do what you asked but you just don't know how to use it for that purpose.  Or maybe your question wasn't clear enough and people thought you were trying to do something that Wireshark does do.  If another answer works for you then it's fine to accept it, but you might be overlooking valid reasons for upvotes to other answers.  It's not always the case that other answers are bad/half-assed/useless/irrelevant.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: it didn't and I believe I posted a question on Wireshark's forum. But the problem is people mention the product and that's it. Wireshark is complicated to use if you want to do fancy filtering and have to read a lot of docs. People upvote a product. Then you ask them Ok how to do a certain thing.. then you get total silence. You know then they really didn't use the product they are telling you about.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: One of my earlier comments says I don't remember. Trust me.. it has happened. I posted over 200 questions.

Comment: I hardly think that asking a ton of questions really counts as experience when it comes to understanding how the community and the engine work.  Answering, editing, moderating, those are all valuable; asking questions is still important for obvious reasons but is probably the least important out of all possible actions.  Basically, you're bitching that you've had some bad experiences, but refuse to identify any of them so that we can actually help you solve your problem (because the problem obviously can't *possibly* be you).

Comment: (P.S. I'm not saying that the problem *is* you - it might genuinely not be - I'm saying that your clearly-implied *assumption* that the problem *must* be with the system/community is not helping your cause.  Show us something concrete, don't just make vague and unsubstantiated complaints.)

Comment: @Aarobot: the system is not perfect. If you think it is, good for you and meta site will have no activity. yes when you ask many question over a period of a year, you gain experience on expected answers. Questions is the core of the sites. of course it's the most important feature. No questions means no users, no activity, no editing.. no nothing. Everything in meta is about the questions as the core. The system is full of bad answers & useless answers otherwise why do you think we have thousands of downvoted or no vote answers? I don't have the time to go back to my questions and find..

Comment: an an example. The last it happened was a while back.

Comment: *"yes awareness and ranting. There's no solution to changing person's behavior."* -1. We don't have a `[rant]` tag for a reason. There's really nothing in this post that prompts us for a discussion. If you want to solicit other people's ideas or suggest a change, we're all ears.

Comment: Blah blah blah.  You had time to write this rant and a bunch of rambling, nonsensical comments, but "don't have time" to actually find an example of what you're complaining about.  And if you think that questions are the most important feature of a site then maybe you should head on over to Yahoo Answers.

Comment: In other words: URL or it didn't happen!

Comment: @Tony: Looking at your score per post isn't meant to insult nor to suggest that rep is king; rather, votes are the only metric we have for how well people are receiving your questions. To be sure, it's not a really *good* metric, but it's what we've got. A single net vote suggests that your questions are not striking their intended audience as clear and interesting. Since you must do the problem in front of you, the only thing you can work on is the writing. This will *also* address the questions of people mis-identifying duplicates, and cut down on non-responsive answers.

Answer (score 11):

1. Yep. Bad answers happen. Writing *really* clear and concise questions helps but does not prevent them.
2. Good ole pile on. This happens too. Again really clear questions will help, as will clear, fast comments, and downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I can't confirm what you report. In my experience, bad answers tend to get downvoted reliably, *especially* if they bear a well-stated comment saying "this is not it".

Yes, there is a lot of shallow Googled answers, but that's people for ya. Also, people should be less afraid to downvote crap, and read very carefully before upvoting. But all in all, I'd say this aspect of Stack Overflow is functioning *exceptionally* well.

Other than that: What @dmckee says.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions do not exist solely to serve *you.* They do exist to serve you, no doubt, but they also exist to serve the rest of the community and the rest of the Google-using populace *as well.*

This is why an accepted answer (as being "best" to the author, for his/her specific needs) may not necessarily be the highest-voted (IE, the one the rest of the community thinks is best). This is perfectly fine, and is in fact, by design. You have your "best," the rest of us have ours.

If you're getting irrelevant answers, the correct response to them is the downvote button. Sure, it costs 1 rep to do it, and only costs the recipient 2, but the point is to lower the score of the answer -- rep be damned. If you think an answer is wrong, you downvote it. That is your responsibility, and your best way of providing feedback that the answer will not work for you.

I see you have voted, both up and down. Perhaps it's time to vote down more often -- if you're getting as many wrong answers as you say you are, *let the answerers know!*

(And only 40 votes for 225 questions and 25 answers? You might consider voting more in general. By my math, your 61% accept rate indicates that you've accepted well over 130 answers to your questions -- you didn't vote even on all of those?)